# TableView crashes when i scroll it repetitatively and it contains 158 cells at the same time.How can i fix this?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My TableView crashes when i scroll it repetitively and it contains 158 cells loaded at the same time.In each cell, I am adding two more labels like

```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cityLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, 190, 20)] autorelease];
    cityLabel.tag = kCityLabelTag;
    cityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cityLabel];

    nameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 22, 300, 20)] autorelease];
    nameLabel.tag = kNameLabelTag;
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];        

} else {
    // A reusable cell was available, so we just need to get a reference to the subviews using their tags.
    cityLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kCityLabelTag];
    nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kNameLabelTag];
}
```

If I release any one of them inside the function, that space where label comes go black and so I cant release the labels there. But after some heavy scrolling it crashes.

How can i fix this?

Comment: what you get in debugger log...?

Comment: Can you show us some code too?  Particularly where you initialise your cells (cellForRowAtIndexPath)

Comment: I have showed the error above. Sorry to reply so late. Can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. Sorry to bother u all. It was caused by one of deallocation that i done unwantedly. Thanks.